# tcdrain function call with ndk toolchain for android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, libc, toolchain

I'm trying to use *tcdrain* function call defined in *termios.h* by compiling my c code with the android ndk.

I'm having issues because when I build the newest android ndk, *tcdrain* is not defined in termios.h, however if I go inside the android source code it is defined in *termios.h* for bionic.

For example: https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/termios.h#L44

But when I build the ndk, it seems to have a different *termios.h* file in *sysroot/usr/include/termios.h*?

Why would the newest ndk not have the same include files as the newest bionic/libc files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code you linked states that those functions are defined only if the following holds

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 21
```

so, as nayuta said you will have `tcdrain` only with build environment configured with `--platform=android21`.

If you can not use plafform android21, you may still define yourself the functions you need.

In case of tcdrain a possible replacement would be

```
#define tcdrain(fd) ioctl(fd, TCSBRK, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your build environment with `--platform=android21` or later?

Before android 5.0, api level 20 and older, function declarations is replaced with `android/legacy_termios_inlines. h`.

If you configure for android 5.0 or later, you can use `tcdrain`.